# Ubuntu 14.04 takes several boot "tries" from GRUB to start because of critical temperature(?)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, temperature

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04, and my problems with the upgrade so far is that for some reason, it always takes me several tries to "boot" Ubuntu for it to start, always with the warning about "critical temperature" after selecting Ubuntu from Grub, and then my laptop shuts down with a noticeable clicking sound from my hard drive.

I have to attempt booting it several times always, and then wait for a while and then attempt to boot again just to successfully boot the system.

This happened before with my 12.04 one, but it happened rarely. The temperature reached according to the stats as I see it is around 100 degree celsius.

I'm using a MSI FX420. I tried to look into using sensors for detecting the heat of my laptop usually, and the output says that it's usually around 79 degree celsius.

So I have no idea where that 100 degree celsius came from.

Is this a bug or something?